# Is the await keyword needed if I call an async function containing an await in its body without the await keyword within another async function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

Step 1: I have function. This function has no return. Anyway I the async keyword to the function because I need to use an await inside this function.

Explanatory code example:

```
const foo1 = async () => {
    const a1 = await something... //For example findValueInDatabase()
}
```

Step 2:
I define another async function again using await inside its body. No return again.

Explanatory code example:

```
const foo2 = async () => {
    const a2 = await something... //For example sendEmail()
}
```

Step 2: Now I want to call the function defined in step 2 inside the function of stop one:

Explanatory code example:

```
const foo1 = async () => {
    const a1 = await something... //For example findValueInDatabase()

    foo2() //or await foo2()

    ...some more code to be executed...
}
```

Expections and questions regarding the behaviour of foo2 within foo1:

Do I need to add the await keyword to foo2 in order for it to be awaited? Does it make a difference? If so, what is the difference?

I would expect that the answer to that question is no.
foo2 will execute and in it a2 will be awaited which means that further code will not be executed until a2 is resolved. So await would not make any difference because calling foo2 within foo1 is like if the code of foo2 was directly in foo1.

Are my expectations wrong?

Comment: *"Do I need to add the await keyword [...] in order for it to be awaited?"*  Yes, that's exactly what that keyword does.  *"what is the difference?"* - If the operation is awaited, the next operation(s) won't be invoked until the Promise is resolved.  If it's not awaited then the code will continue to the next operation(s) without waiting for the Promise to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All async functions return a promise. If you care about the results of the promise, you can use await or the promise.then function. But if there's no return and/or you don't care about the return, you don't need `await/then`

In foo1 you can use `await` on foo2 to ensure foo1 completes after foo2

Comment: So async functions return a promise even if there is no return statement inside their body?

Comment: Yes. Async functions are guaranteed to return a promise. And if your return something other than a promise in an async function, that value will be the `resolved` value of the promise.

Comment: So your final answer would suggest that if I do not add the await keyword to foo2, foo1 would continue its execution before foo2's execution is finished? Is that correct?

Comment: @JakobBasshunterWidmann this is correct. (Browser) Ecmascript/JavaScript is single threaded, so when you are not using await, foo1 needs to exit before foo2 can run

Answer (score 1):

The `await` keyword tells the execution of your function to "await" `foo2()` before continuing. If you omit the `await` the code in `foo2()` will still run but `foo1()` will also continue on without making sure `foo2()` has completed. This is definitely allowed, just be careful because this can lead to [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

Comment: If I could accept two answers I would accept yours too. Sorry :(